# Silverlight + WCF (Database operation) is not safe (privacy) ?

Tags: .net, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

SILVERLIGHT IS Not SAFE (privacy)

We developed project with silverlight + wcf. We all scared about the xap file decompilers. May be code and function are not safe using silverlight.

I am prepared application using SL4 + WCF. Then i try to find some sample in silverlight application. i got some crazy software here screen snap below

Silverlight Spy is an deployment application of XAP.

[image: Silverlight Spy is an deployment application]

here we download all **dll** and **service config** files. Now we have a service url then  using WCF Test Client Application access service function !

[image: WCF Test Client]

**DLL's:** Decompiler of DLL's already available!!

[image: Decompiler of DLL]

Here i wanna know how to make secure code using silverlight ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decompilers work for all the applications targeting .net framework and not just silverlight. If you want to hide the implementation of code, there are several free and commerical obfuscators in the market for that purpose.

Comment: ok. We hide the dll and config file are in web app (ASP.Net). But silverlight how?. All things are compressed with one XAP!

Comment: XAP is the package that is downloaded on the client machine and Silverlight runtime unzips it and hosts it in the browser. XAP package is nothing but a zip file of all the dll's. You can even change the extension from .xap to .zip and see it yourself. XAP would be downloaded at the client machine and hence you can't hide it. If your requirement is that no user should get hold of xap file and can decompile it, I would suggest go for full ASP.Net solution.